# Doing Matrix<double> instantiation programatically (Math.Net C# Library)

Tags: c#, matrix, mathnet-numerics

I know this is going to sound like a very beginner question but I'm using this C# library and even after reading the references, I'm not able to figure out how to do the following code.

Matrix Class Documentation is at https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix%601.htm

I'm trying to do something similar to this but I can't figure it out

```
Matrix<double> matrix = new Matrix<double>();
matrix.Add(new List<double> list1());
matrix.Add(new List<double> list2());
```

This is what I have done so far to create a Matrix object and what I'm trying to do is create a Matrix for any amount instead of having to do a fixed amount in my code.

```
var matrixArrayBuy = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(0).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(1).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(2).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                            listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(3).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(4).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(5).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(6).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                            listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(7).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(8).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(9).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(), listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(10).ListValuesBuy.ToArray(),
                            listMRInfoBuy.ElementAt(11).ListValuesBuy.ToArray());
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sure, it’s similar to some code you showed us. But what is it exactly? What problems are you encountering? Are you asking how to add another matrix to this one? If so, what problem are you having with that?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I edited my code to show you how I'm doing it now and all I'm trying to do is create a matrix for N amount of inputs so I feel really stupid not being able to figure something so simple out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your listMRInfoBuy variable is, but could try something like:

```
    List<double[]> matrixParams = new List<double[]>();

    foreach (var item in listMRInfoBuy.Elements)
    {
        matrixParams.Add(item.ListValuesBuy.ToArray());
    }


    var matrixArrayBuy = CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumnArrays(matrixParams);
```

Comment: listMRInfoBuy is a list of a custom class that I created

Comment: Well I feel like a complete idiot because this code was what I somehow missed with my attempts. Big thanks!

Comment: Assuming both `listMRInfoBuy` and `.ListValuesBuy` are enumerables, you could simplify this to `CreateMatrix.DenseOfColumns(listMRInfoBuy.Select(x => x.ListValuesBuy))`